# Java NPE for String Length

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

```
String temp_content = null;

while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
{   
    if(temp_content.length() == 0) /* NPE */
    {
         temp_content = line;
    }
    else
    {
        temp_content = temp_content+line;
    } 
}
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` at the above indicated line.
Is it wrong to use  `"temp_content.length() == 0"` to find out if the string is `null`?.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You should initialize your string variable like temp="" or temp=new temp(); when you are try to perform any function in null object you will get NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be :

```
String temp_content = null;

while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
{   
    if(temp_content == null)
    {
     temp_content = line;
    }
    else
    {
        temp_content += line;
    } 
}
```

Using `StringBuilder` will make it even better :

```
StringBuilder temp_content = new StringBuilder();

while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
{   

        temp_content.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`temp_content` is initialized to `null`. Make sure its initialized to empty string to avoid NPE

```
String temp_content = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

`temp_content` is `null`, so calling `.length()` on it is like calling `null.length()`, which causes a `NullPointerException`.  In order for this not to happen, you must initialize it:

```
temp_context = "";
```

**To determine if a `String` is `null`, you can use:**

```
if (temp_content == null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `temp_content` is `null` and you are calling an `instance` methond on `null` reference.

If you want to know whether a String is **null**, then you need to use `==` to verify the same.

```
if (temp_content == null) {
   System.out.println("String is null");
}
```

***NPE*** is thrown everytime you try to invoke an `instance` method on ***null*** reference.

**Note:** *NPE* is NOT thrown when invoking a **static** method on `null` reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your string variable like temp="" or temp=new temp(); when you are try to perform any function in null object you will get NPE.